# c++ error:unrecognized command line option '-msse3'

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, g++, nvidia

I am trying to make an executable file on the NVIDIA jetson tx1 （with g++ and gcc, both versions are 5.4.0）. But the compilation fails:

[image: screenshot]

It doesn't fail on other Linux distributions.

Comment: Hey, I'm stuck on the same error, did you fix this?

Answer (score 1):

SSE3 is an x86 feature, and a NVidia jetson tx1 is not an x86 processor.